# cineworld api info blank

Tags: jquery, api

hi there im new to using API's and am having problems trying to retrive info from the cineworld api, has any one used it at all.

here is an example that they give, but i cant seem to pull any info from it?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.retrieve').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/quickbook/films',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {key: 'qUnEyRXt', full: true, cinema: 33},
        dataType: 'jsonp', // Setting this data type will add the callback parameter for you
        success: parseFilms
    });
});

$('a.clear').click(function() {
    $('span.film.count').text('0');
    $('ol.film.list').empty();
});
});

 function parseFilms(response, status) {
var html = '';

// Check for errors from the server
if (response.errors) {
    $.each(response.errors, function() {
        html += '<li>' + this + '</li>';
    });
} else {
    $('span.film.count').text(response.films.length);
    $.each(response.films, function() {
        html += '<li>' + this.title + ' (' + this.classification + ')</li>';
    });
}

// Faster than doing a DOM call to append each node
$('ol.film.list').append(html);
}


</script>
```

the web documation is link is https://www.cineworld.co.uk/developer/jquery

any help or advice would be great thanks alot

Comment: +1 for showing the data of Cineworld api. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want your api key in there?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works!

Here is the **url that you're passing** on `$.ajax()`:

http://www.cineworld.co.uk/api/quickbook/films?key=qUnEyRXt&full=true&cinema=33

**Here is the code**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.retrieve').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
              url: 'http://www.cineworld.co.uk/api/quickbook/films',
              type: 'GET',
              data: {key: 'qUnEyRXt', full: true, cinema: 33},
              dataType: 'jsonp', // Setting this data type will add the callback parameter for you
              success: parseFilms
          });
        });

        $('a.clear').click(function() {
            $('span.film.count').text('0');
            $('ol.film.list').empty();
        });
      });

      function parseFilms(response, status) {
        var html = '';

        // Check for errors from the server
        if (response.errors) {
            $.each(response.errors, function() {
                html += '<li>Error' + this + '</li>';
            });
        } else {
            $('span.film.count').text(response.films.length);
            $.each(response.films, function() {
                html += '<li>' + this.title + ' (' + this.classification + ')</li>';
            });
        }

        // Faster than doing a DOM call to append each node
        $('ol.film.list').html(html);
      }
    </script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="retrieve" href="#retrieve">Retrieve</a>
    <a class="clear" href="#clear">Clear</a>
    <span class="film count"></span>
    <ol class="film list">
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By, the way, just on a side note advise. So, you can read the json string, you might want to download a json reader plugin on your browser.